# How do you use an fbx file in OpenGL on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fbx

Is there a library that is commonly used?  If all else fails, I'll just write something myself for importing the files, they don't seem too complicated, but I was wondering if there was an easier way, like an open source project or something.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the FBX SDK provided by Autodesk. It supports iOS since a few releases now.

Comment: ... with the only negative being that, I believe, Autodesk still supplies it only as an ARMv7 binary. No ARMv7s, no ARM64. So your general code won't work as well as it otherwise might on the iPhone 5 or beyond.

Comment: Just checked and they now have armv7+armv7s+arm64 in their latest FBX 2015.1 beta. I would expect they have the release version out soon. But still, anyone can grab the beta version since the FBX beta is freely open.

Comment: the Autodesk FBX SDK is compatible with the App Store as Autodesk published the latest version of it FBX Review tool. See also this tutorial which demos the configuration: http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2014/07/an-fbx-sdk-ios-quick-tutorial.html

Comment: is anyone able to display animation from fbx file within opengles2? any tutorials available?

Comment: @Deathicon any demo available that show how to render .fbx in mobile screen.