# How to import .FBX file in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, 3d

Is there a way to open FBX files (used for showing 3D models) in iOS SDK?

There is a similar question asked before, but that is unanswered as well.

[How do you use an fbx file in OpenGL on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578305/how-do-you-use-an-fbx-file-in-opengl-on-ios)

Please let me know.

Any other inputs in this regards would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The FBX SDK now supports iOS, so you should be able to access its content just like any other platforms.

Also, I heard FBX Review is coming to iOS.